# Is it possible to take cards details from client side for PayPal payment integration?

Tags: paypal

As per my knowledge, we can use paypal button on front end side and when user click on that button it'll redirect to paypal website and there we need to login and we can pay.

> But i want, user should enter all payment details(like card details)
>   in my website and payment will credit to my paypal account.

Is it possible ? if it is possible then how to implement that ?

Comment: This seems very sketchy...why would you want the users card details? You should not be handling that kind of information unless you are a billion times sure that it's not going to get leaked and even then I'd still be hesitant

Comment: My application is secured, and no user data will leak, so i don't want user to redirect to paypal website to enter card details for payment. i want user to enter card details in my website only. @AFriend

Comment: Firstly, from a UX side of things, its better to go through paypal. Let the redirect happen. Users will appreciate seeing that they're secure. There should be no reason that you need to inject yourself here. Paypal can manage all your payments and there should be no reason for you to also make note of the card details used. Secondly, it opens you up to a whole range of attacks, paypal has top-notch security and manages all that for you. If you want to hold card details seperatly from paypal you'll have to have a seperate form that you can control - **but I would highly advise against that**